# Unable to add Zscaler certificates to Ubuntu trusted store

Tags: certificates, pem

I have a set of three certificates to form a trusted chain from Zscaler but I cannot install them in the Ubuntu trusted store.

[image]

The three corresponding certificates are there for reference:

- [Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscloud.net) (t)](https://gist.github.com/springcomp/5e911272619593a3e9df2b373246a43e)
- [Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscloud.net)](https://gist.github.com/springcomp/1af33786af7299f9641d7fd5fc552880)
- [Zscaler Root CA](https://gist.github.com/springcomp/b66a928919bc6636acc19dcc658286c3)

When trying to add them to the trusted store, I stumble upon the warning:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
rehash: warning: skipping Zscaler_Root_CA.pem,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
…
```

This error happens for all three certificates.
As a result the *symlinks* are not created in `/etc/ssl/certs/`.

Therefore, when using `openssl`, `wget` or `curl` to download various files, I get errors similar to this one:

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`
```

I tried manually creating the *symlinks* with the correct hashes but this did not resolve my issue. When I specify `-CAfile` directly to `openssl` it succeeds, but I cannot do this for other tools such as `wget` or `curl`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did the certificates added to /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt file? And where are you storing all these certificates for updating? I mean for running update-ca-certificates.

Comment: Yes I converted them to binary .crt files, copied them to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and ran update-ca-certificates. Also tried to copy them in /usr/share/ca-certificates/Zscaler and run dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates. Both times, certificates were added ok, but none of the hashed symlinks were created.

Comment: Even though they are copied as .crt files, update-ca-certificates convert them back to .pem files.

Comment: You do not need to change them to binary format they are already in PEM format on the website you have shared. All the certificates in /etc/ssl/certs are in PEM format. If link is not automatically created use OpenSSL to generate hash and create symlinks with that hash and store the file in PEM format only at /etc/ssl/certs/

Comment: I have done the manual hashing of course, but I still get the "unable to get local issuer certificate" error when trying to use wget, curl, or even openssl to read certificate from a website using Zscaler trust chain.

Comment: Append all the certificate into one file and specify the file in curl command with option --cacert <file> or if you have created symlinks in SSL dir specify --capath <SSL dir> and check. Make sure files should be in pem format. Also, I tried the steps with Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked perfectly fine with update-ca-certificates command.

Comment: Having to specify an extra command option defeats the purpose of installing certificates in the trusted store though, but yes I had tried - albeit only with the root certificate - and it worked. Hum... Interesting so it must be an Ubuntu 20.04 issue then... Will try with 16.04 and report. Thanks.